# HTML5 tab hyperlink to pop-up

Tags: css, html

I have done a lot of research before posting it in here. So, here I got few imperfections.[my link](http://eminli.net/test)

**Question 1:** How do I make CV button to automatically pop-up the pdf resume or cv. So after I get this done, I won't need div saying lorem as a hyperlink.

Under the navigation class:

```
<li><a href="#cv" target="_blank">CV</a></li>
```

When I replace #cv from href with a pdf link, the whole website goes wrong.

Thats it for now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<li><a href="" onclick="return popitup('cv.pdf')" >CV</a></li>
```

Comment: brakes the html and I see all the tabs in one page after that implementation.

Comment: where you put that script element?... Please put that script before </body> tag

Comment: jscript in body tag did not do the trick, have you tried it yourself?